# Ruby - conversion string to float return 0.0

Tags: ruby, string, floating-point, type-conversion

In a variable is stored this value: `$10.00`
And I need to get this `10.00`

I've tried to convert this value to float:

```
new_price = '%.2f' % (price.to_f)
```

but I get just `0.0`.

What's wrong with that?
I've tried also

```
price = price.strip
price[0]=""
new_price = '%.2f' % (price.to_f)
```

But even this didn't help me... where is a problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 22):

You need to remove the `$` first. The whole thing like this:

```
'%.2f' % '$10.00'.delete( "$" ).to_f
```

or

```
'%.2f' % '$10.00'[1..-1].to_f
```

if you like density and may encounter non dollars.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the output is still just `10.0` instead of `10.00`.

Comment: not for me 

    `1.9.3-p392 :006 > '%.2f' % '$10.00'.delete( "$" ).to_f
    => "10.00"`

Comment: In totally the same way as you do, the only difference is that the value is stored in database

Comment: ok - that is weird. You probably have to post a bit more code for me to have an idea. What ruby are you on?

Comment: I am running on `ruby 1.9.3p385`.

Answer (score 0):

To set it in a variable:

```
 current_price= '%.2f' % '$10.00'.delete( "$" ).to_f
```

The more common error, is a value in the thousands where there's a comma in the string like: 10,000.00. The comma will cause the same truncation error, but the decimal won't, and many programmers won't even catch it (we don't even notice the comma anymore). To fix that:

```
current_price= '%.2f' % '10,000.00'.delete( "," ).to_f
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding on to froderick's answer of:

> You need to remove the $ first. The whole thing like this:

```
'%.2f' % '$10.00'.delete( "$" ).to_f
```

> or

```
'%.2f' % '$10.00'[1..-1].to_f
```

> if you like density and may encounter non dollars.
>   you need to format the code for output to ensure that you get two decimal places >with

You need to format your output string to ensure you get two decimal places.

```
puts "Current amount: #{format("%.2f", amount)}"
```